# JFrame and JTextField not appearing?

Tags: java, swing

So I've recently started to learn Java but something has me puzzled. The issue is that when I run the program, only the window pops up but no text box.

Code:

```
public void createWindow(int height, int width, String title) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(width, height);
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        window.add(jp);
        JTextField jt = new JTextField(30);
        jp.add(jt);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue is that when i run the program, only the window pops up but
>   no text box.

Do not call setVisible(..) before all components have been added to the JFrame, this was the cause of your problem.

The below code should work.

```
public void createWindow(int height, int width, String title) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setSize(width, height);
    window.setTitle(title);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JTextField jt = new JTextField(30);
    jp.add(jt);
    window.add(jp);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```